# Various android application home screen design patterns

Tags: android

I am completely newer in android application development. Now I am something familiar with Dashboard design patterns [Click here](http://www.xoriant.com/blog/mobile-application-development/android-ui-design-pattern-dashboard-howto.html)  . And I would like to know more about UI design patterns. Is there any one who know about various design patterns or design tips to create simple and more user friendly User interface designs in android.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [androidpatterns.com](http://www.androidpatterns.com/) covers many patterns which are used on android.

Comment: // , Good question. Have you read any books on the subject, Noufal?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.androidpatterns.com/) or [here](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/p/android-ui-pattern-collection.html) is some information about UI patterns. For start it will be useful